# Text Animations with Tkinter

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, canvas

I'm designing a GUI to decrease the time which my colleagues spend for reporting tests. But I stuck in the animation of opening screen. I mixed the code that I found on the internet which writes the chosen text letter one by one with a second for loop to enlarge the text but the first loop worked only for the last word of the list. Also, I tried the same code with a while loop both with giving count or just writing "True" but they didn't solve my problem either.

I want to see the chosen texts (now, only a few words but later on I will write my tests) written on the screen one by one and letter by letter. How can I solve this?

My sketch code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")

Words=["Canvas", "Import", "Index", "Random", "Tkinter"]


canvas=tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=375, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

for word in Words:
    x=random.randint(0, 250)
    y=random.randint(0, 225)
    canvas_text=canvas.create_text(x, y, text=word)
    delta=500 
    delay=0
    for i in range(len(word)+1):
        s=word[:i]
        update_text=lambda s=s: canvas.itemconfigure(canvas_text, text=s)
        canvas.after(delay, update_text)
        delay+=delta
        x=random.randint(0, 250)
        y=random.randint(0, 225)
        
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Image description]

Comment: Can you more clearly describe the behaviour that you expect to see? 
Not sure what this little animation has to do with reporting tests, seems like a distraction from the real problem.

Comment: I just want to see the names of the tests randomly one by one on the screen when program is not working because I don't want an empty canvas. Now all the names came at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

1. With `canvas_text = canvas.create_text(x, y, text=word)` you immediately write the full word, it would make more sense to start with an empty string, `canvas_text = canvas.create_text(x, y, text="")`, then add the letters one by one. Additionally, you can add the option `anchor="w"` so that adding the letters will not move the word (otherwise the default anchor is the center of the object).
2. `delay` is reset to 0 for each word so the letters will appear one by one but at the same time for all words.
3. `update_text` is defined as `lambda s=s: canvas.itemconfigure(canvas_text, text=s)` and therefore `canvas_text` refers to the last created canvas object (see [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)). As a consquence, only the last word is animated. To avoid this, you can use an additional argument in the function:  `lambda s=s, c=canvas_text: canvas.itemconfigure(c, text=s)`
4. A few additional remarks:

   - `delta=500`  can be moved out of the for loop
   - The `x = ...` and `y = ...` in the nested for loop are useless and can be removed
   - `update_text=lambda s=s: canvas.itemconfigure(canvas_text, text=s)`: `lambda` is typically used to avoid having to give the function a name, so one typically either defines a named function with `def` or uses a `lambda` directly, e.g.

     ```
     canvas.after(delay, lambda c=canvas_text, s=word[:i]: canvas.itemconfigure(c, text=s))
     ```

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")

Words = ["Canvas", "Import", "Index", "Random", "Tkinter"]

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=375, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
delay = 0
delta = 500
for word in Words:
    x = random.randint(0, 250)
    y = random.randint(0, 225)
    canvas_text = canvas.create_text(x, y, text="", anchor="w")

    for i in range(len(word)+1):
        canvas.after(delay, lambda c=canvas_text, s=word[:i]: canvas.itemconfigure(c, text=s))
        delay += delta

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you j_4321, this is what I want!